# Is a Simple Storage Pool the same as software RAID 0 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, raid, software-raid

I have a single SSD in my PC as a boot drive with two 1TB HDDs that I'd like to setup in RAID 0.  I'm not storing anything important in RAID 0, just my Steam library.  I figured setting the drives up in RAID 0 would improve my load speeds.

If I create a storage space using the "simple" setting (no parity), is this the same as software RAID 0, or is the same as JBOD?

Comment: Storage Spaces closes resembles a RAID configuration not JBOD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Simple (No Parity) resiliency option allows you to create a raid 0 or JBOD.

When adding the disk drive to the storage pool check the box that says `Optimize drive performance across all drives` to set up raid 0 or Un-Check the box to set up `JBOD`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a RAID0-like result you need to use PowerShell; the parameter -NumberOfColumns 1,

-NumberOfColumns 2 like RAID 5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

No, a "simple" storage spaces configuration is a spanned (like JBOD SPAN) and not striped (like RAID0) setup.

To get a RAID0-like result you need to use PowerShell; the parameter `-NumberOfColumns 2` would mean striping across two disks.